# Batch Lines not showing up correctly

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd

Trying to add some lines ╔═╬ to my batch files. The issue I am having is that they do not show up properly in CMD.

I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Show us your batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use CHCP 65001 to get the characters to work correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your codepage, maybe? In your bat file, issue a [chcp 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Comment: I have found that I needed to change to UT8 and use `chcp 65001`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this one a few times... Open the file in Notepad and Save as ... make sure to change the Encoding to ANSI  ...  (right next to the Save button)